# ¿Por qué FPDF, no imprime el primer registro obtenido de una consulta multitabla, y lo acentos no los imprime?

Tags: php, mysqli

```html
<?php

require('conexion.php');
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF 
{
 function AcceptPageBreak()
 {
  $this->Addpage();

  //$this->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',9);

        $this->SetX(10);//posisionamos en 10 de x
        $this->Cell(10,6,'NUM.',1,0,'C',1);//

        $this->SetX(20);//posisionamos en 10 de x
        $this->Cell(27,6,'MATRICULA',1,0,'C',1);//

        $this->SetX(47);
        $this->Cell(76,6,'NOMBRE',1,0,'C',1); 

        $this->Ln();
    }

        function Header()
 {
  //logo
  $this->Image('logo2.png',10,8,33);
  //fuente
  $this->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
  //movernos a la derecha como sangria
  $this->Cell(65);
        //movernos a la derecha como sangria
  $this->Cell(70,10,'CEB: Listado Grupo',1,0,'C');//tamaños,texto,contorno 1, salto de linea despues de la selda, alineacion
  //salto de linea
  $this->Ln(20);
 }

 function Footer()
 {   //desde hacia arriba 15 puntos, coordenadas, a 1.5 cm del final
  $this->SetY(-15);
  //arial italic 8
  $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
  //num de pagina
  $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');

 }

 
}

if(isset($_GET['gpo']))  {

 $grupos = $_GET['gpo'];  //RECIBIMOS EL PARAMETRO POR URL : EL ID DE LA TABLA ALUMNO_GRUPO
}


$consulta = "SELECT A.grupo, A.matricula, A.nombre as na, P.clave, P.nombre as np, P.apellidos as ap, M.materia as mm, M.Clave_Materia as cl, G.periodo as periodo, G.lunes, G.turno as turno, G.martes, G.miercoles, G.jueves, G.viernes FROM materias M, alumno A, alumno_grupo AG, grupos G, profesores P WHERE M.idMateria = G.materia and A.idAlumno= AG.idAlumno and G.idGrupo = AG.idGrupo and G.profesor = P.idProfesor and AG.idGrupo = '$grupos'";


$res=$mysqli->query($consulta);

$pdf = new PDF();

$pdf->Addpage();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if ( $fila2 = $res->fetch_assoc() )   {
 //$dos=$fila2['mm'];

$pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',8);

 $pdf->SetX(10);//posisionamos en 10 de x
 $pdf->Cell(22,5,$fila2['periodo'],1,0,'C',1);
 //materia
 $pdf->SetX(33);//posisionamos en 10 de x
 $pdf->Cell(100,5,$fila2['mm'],1,0,'C',1);//colocando ancho de celda
 //turno
 $pdf->SetX(134);//posisionamos en 10 de x
 $pdf->Cell(16,5,$fila2['cl'],1,0,'C',1);

 $pdf->SetX(151);//posisionamos en 10 de x
 $pdf->Cell(22,5,$fila2['turno'],1,0,'C',1);

 $pdf->SetX(174);//posisionamos en 10 de x
 $pdf->Cell(14,5,$fila2['grupo'],1,0,'C',1);

 $pdf->Ln();
 $pdf->Ln();
 
 $pdf->SetX(10);//posiionamos en 10 de x
 $pdf->Cell(32,5,$fila2['clave'],1,0,'C',1);//colocando ancho de celda

 $pdf->SetX(43);//posiionamos en 10 de x
 $pdf->Cell(64,5,$fila2['np'],1,0,'C',1);//colocando ancho de celda

 $pdf->SetX(108);//posisionamos en 10 de x
 $pdf->Cell(80,5,$fila2['ap'],1,0,'C',1);//colocando ancho de celda

 $pdf->Ln();
 $pdf->Ln();
 //HORARIO
 $pdf->SetX(10);//posisionamos en 10 de x
 $pdf->Cell(40,5,'L: '.$fila2['lunes'],1,0,'C',1);//colocando ancho de celda

 $pdf->SetX(51);//posisionamos en 10 de x
 $pdf->Cell(45,5,'M: '.$fila2['martes'],1,0,'C',1);

 $pdf->SetX(97);//posisionamos en 10 de x
 $pdf->Cell(45,5,'M: '.$fila2['miercoles'],1,0,'C',1);

 $pdf->SetX(143);//posisionamos en 10 de x
 $pdf->Cell(45,5,'J: '.$fila2['jueves'],1,0,'C',1);
 $pdf->Ln();
 $pdf->Ln();

 $pdf->SetX(85);//posisionamos en 10 de x
 $pdf->Cell(40,5,'V: '.$fila2['viernes'],1,0,'C',1);

}

 $pdf->Ln();
 $pdf->Ln();

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 $pdf->SetX(10);//posisionamos en 10 de x
 $pdf->Cell(10,6,'NUM.',1,0,'C',1);//colocando ancho de celda

 $pdf->SetX(20);//posisionamos en 10 de x
 $pdf->Cell(27,6,'MATRICULA',1,0,'C',1);//

 $pdf->SetX(47);
 $pdf->Cell(76,6,'NOMBRE',1,0,'C',1);



 $pdf->Ln();
//// Contamos el total de filas recuperadas, $i ira incrementado según el numero de registrpos encontrados, y los enumera/////////////
 $num_ros = mysqli_num_rows($res); 

 $i=0;


 /////////////////////////////////////////// IMPRESION DE LOS DATOS
while ($fila = $res->fetch_assoc())
{
 if($i<=$num_ros) { 
 $i++;  //contador para el Num de Lista

 $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
 
 $pdf->SetX(10);//posisionamos en 10 de x
    $pdf->Cell(10,6,$i,1,0,'C');  //num, impreso

    }

    $pdf->SetX(20);//matricula alumno
    $pdf->Cell(27,6, $fila['matricula'],1,0,'C',0);//

    $pdf->SetX(47);//nombre alumno
    $pdf->Cell(76,6, utf8_decode($fila['na']),1,1,'C',0);

}

$pdf->Output();

?>
```

Comment: la misma consulta directa en mysql, si devuelve todos los registros completos, de alumnos, pero en fpdf no devuelve el primero, los demás si.

Comment: Haz un var_dump de `$fila2` para ver si te devuelve el primer registro.

Comment: seria en $fila, $fila2 la ocupo para encabezados, $fila para registros de alumnos, ya la puse var_dump($fila); pero no arroja el primer registro

Comment: ¿Pero los valores de matricula y na se ven correctamente?

Comment: ¿valores devueltos con var_dump? se refiere?

Comment: Sí. Mira mi respuesta. Creo que te podrá ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No te crea el primer valor porque te lo saltas cuando usas `i++` al principio del bucle. Lo deberías de usar al final del método while.

Usando tu bucle, en la primera iteración va a realizar lo siguiente:

```
$i=0;
while ($fila = $res->fetch_assoc())
{
    //Aqui la variable $i vale 0
    if($i<=$num_ros) { 
        $i++;  //Aquí la variable $i vale 1

        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);

        $pdf->SetX(10);
        $pdf->Cell(10,6,$i,1,0,'C');  //Va a imprimir 1 en vez de 0
    }

    $pdf->SetX(20);
    $pdf->Cell(27,6, $fila['matricula'],1,0,'C',0);

    $pdf->SetX(47);
    $pdf->Cell(76,6, utf8_decode($fila['na']),1,1,'C',0);
}
```

Por otro lado, si usas el `i++` al final del bucle:

```
$i=0;
while ($fila = $res->fetch_assoc())
{
    //Aqui la variable $i vale 0
    if($i<=$num_ros) { 
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);

        $pdf->SetX(10);
        $pdf->Cell(10,6,$i,1,0,'C');  //Va a imprimir 0 ya que no has modificado el valor todavía
    }

    $pdf->SetX(20);
    $pdf->Cell(27,6, $fila['matricula'],1,0,'C',0);

    $pdf->SetX(47);//nombre alumno
    $pdf->Cell(76,6, utf8_decode($fila['na']),1,1,'C',0);

    $i++;  //Aquí la variable $i vale 1 (para la siguiente iteración)
}
```

Como puedes observar, necesitas añadir un valor más al actual a la variable `i` al final del método while y no en medio ya que si no el primer número de registro "se lo va a saltar".

El problema de que los acentos no se te vean, tal y como documenta en el apartado FAQ de FPDF, es problema de codificación. Ellos te recomiendan usar `utf8_decode()` como puedes ver [aquí](http://www.fpdf.org/en/FAQ.php#q3).

Comment: tiene razón, pero parece que aun no me imprime el primer registro, el contador solo numera las filas obtenidas, pero incluso quitando el contador no imprime ese primer registro

Comment: @ArmandoArellano Sí, yo tampoco veía que eso pudiera afectar demasiado pero pensaba que sólo no se imprimía el número de registro en el pdf. Sospecho que el problema está en que usas dos veces `fetch_assoc()` sobre la misma consulta. Prueba a hacer de nuevo la query para el registro de los datos y con otro nombre: `$res2=$mysqli->query($consulta);`. Luego usa esta para el bucle while y dime que te recupera.

Comment: creo que si era eso, ya lo esta imprimiendo al parecer, muchas gracias, solo me quedaria lo de los acentos, le agradesco mucho saludos

Comment: @ArmandoArellano Para lo de los acentos usa `utf8_decode(tuString)` con lo strings en los que tengas problemas. De esta manera se te imprimirán correctamente en tu pdf.

Comment: asi lo tengo:
$pdf->SetX(47);//nombre alumno
$pdf->Cell(76,6, utf8_decode($fila['na']),1,1,'C',0);

Comment: Pero no sale. no se si porque los nombres en tabla estan en mayusculas, y a algunos nombres tienen acentos

Comment: @ArmandoArellano ¿En la base de datos se te muestran bien?

Comment: Si mire, por ejemplo:
BASABE ROMÁN  NICOLÁS GUADALUPE

Comment: @ArmandoArellano Prueba usando `utf8_encode(tuString)` en vez de `utf8_decode`.

Comment: los divide asi: Ã•VILA MARTÃ•NEZ ROSSELYN LIZZETH

Comment: @ArmandoArellano Que raro, más que nada porque el propio FPDF te recomienda usar utf8_decode para este tipo de casos. Igual es algún tipo de bug sobre el FDPF. De todas maneras, yo abriría otra pregunta para el problema de los acentos.

Comment: de acuerdo muchas gracias por todo saludos

Comment: @ArmandoArellano De nada :) Me alegra saber que te he sido de ayuda ^^

Comment: muchas gracias, saludos